# PHP Update Query wont update

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I'm trying to create a brute force protection on my login script. Although the query that's supposed to update the database that the account is locked wont work. I'm starting to get frustrated since I've been looking at this code for the last half hour..

Anyway here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$mysqli = getConnected('*','*','*','*');
$username = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['password']);
$hash = sha1($password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if($data['lock'] == 0) {
        if($hash == $data['password']) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $result->free();
        $mysqli->close();
        header("Location: index.php?p=start");
        } else {
            if($data['login_attempts'] != 0) {
                $attempts_left = $data['login_attempts'] - 1;
                $query2 = "UPDATE users SET login_attempts='$attempts_left' WHERE username='$username'";
                $mysqli->query($query2);
                echo "Inloggningen misslyckades, du har ". $attempts_left ." försök kvar.";
            } else {
                $query3 = "UPDATE users SET lock='1' WHERE username='$username'";
                $mysqli->query($query3);
                echo "Ditt konto har låsts.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Ditt konto är låst, kontakta webmaster för att återställa det.";
    }
}
```

the problem is where $query3 is executed, although it executes correctly according to var_dump.

I need some second set of eyes to make sure im not going crazy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `lock` is a [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to change your query to:

```
$query3 = "UPDATE users SET `lock`='1' WHERE username='$username'";
                            ^^^^^^ use back-ticks to escape reserved words in mysql
```

Comment: Thank you! You relieved me of this tedious problem!